# Relationship between the eigenvalues of A and LU

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is decomposed into LU (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), like to know how the eigenvalues of A are related to eigenvalues of L and U separately when A is decomposed into LU?

Comment: what are eigenvalues of $B=LU$ if $A=B$??

Comment: same right?....

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see the "eigevalues of L and U separately" part. Let met try it. If $A$ is Positive (Semi)Definite, then the eigenvalues of A are square roots of diagonal entries of $L$ and $U=L^T$. General case, let me try.

Comment: @dineshdileep That is not true, you cannot recover eigenvalues of $A$ from its LU or Cholesky factorization so easily. Otherwise computing eigenvalues would be a trivial issue without any need to solve for roots of polynomials.